# Google Apps Script - How do i get my AdminDirectory.Users.List query to be accepted?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using GAS to create a contact lookup, where the function parameters build a query that is used in **AdminDirectory.Users.List** . This problem only happens when the **orgTitle** and **orgDepartment** parameters are used. When I copy and paste the Logger output in place of the **q** variable, the query works. If I used the q variable, it fails.

```js
function listAllUsersBase(name = null, familyName = null, givenName = null, orgTitle = 'Help Desk', orgDepartment = null) {
  
  var aQuery = 'query:\''
  
    if (name !== null){
    Logger.log('Name: ' + name);
    var aQuery = aQuery + 'name:' + name + ' ';
  } if (familyName !== null){
    Logger.log('familyName: ' + familyName);
    var aQuery = aQuery + 'familyName:' + familyName + ' ';
  } if (givenName !== null){
    Logger.log('givenName: ' + givenName);
    var aQuery = aQuery + 'givenName:' + givenName + ' ';
  } if (orgTitle !== null){
    Logger.log('orgTitle: ' + orgTitle);
    var aQuery = aQuery + 'orgTitle:\\\'' + orgTitle + '\\\' ';
    
  } if (orgDepartment !== null){
    Logger.log('orgDepartment: ' + orgDepartment)
    var aQuery = aQuery + 'orgDepartment:\\\'' + orgDepartment + '\\\' ';
  }
  
  var aQuery = aQuery + '\''
  var q = aQuery.toString();
  
  Logger.log(q);
 
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'yourdomain.com',
      query: q,
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your script.

First, you do not need to re-declare the **`aQuery`** variable. The first declaration of **`var aQuery = ...`** is sufficient for your use-case.

Second, **`query`** is not a valid field for a search clause so it is not necessary ([see documentation with list of valid fields available to search clauses](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users)). To clarify, when you first declare your **`aQuery`** variable you initialized it as `var aQuery = 'query:\'';`. Here, **`query`** is being used as a field in a search clause. However, it is not a valid option in this context.

Third, the position of the opening single-quotes on the field values for **`orgTitle`** and **`orgDepartment`** are incorrect, the opening **escaped** single-quote should precede the **escaped** backslash.

So, instead of:

```js
var aQuery = aQuery + 'orgTitle:\\\'' + orgTitle + '\\\' ';
```

you should have:

```js
var aQuery = aQuery + 'orgTitle:\'\\' + orgTitle + '\\\' ';
```

Comment: Hey there. I went ahead and tried your suggestions to no avail. I should have removed the q variable, however I just left it in for testing. I also checked the documentation and **query** is valid a valid field noted [here.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) Lastly, the escaped \' is required within the query. If you copy and past the logged q variable, it works. Thank you for your input on this, it's much appreciated.

Comment: It is a valid **parameter** for the Users:list endpoint. But it is **not** a valid **field** for a **search clause**. They are two distinct concepts (ie. **parameters** and search clause **fields**).

Comment: Never said that the escaped single quote isn't required. You just didn't place the opening single-quote correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify the second issue and put bold on key words in the 3rd issue for emphasis.